# How can I pass a DOM element to an HTML attribute? ReactJs/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to pass react element to html attribute:

```
let element = (
<div>
   <div> test</div>
    <div> <span> test333</span></div>
</div>
)
<div data-react = {element}></div>
```

However I get `"object Object"` inside the data-react attribute, is there a way I could use a method to pass dom element and use that inside my render function?

This is the expected o/p I'm trying to get to render it as a react element:
[image]

UPDATE:::::::::
So here is what I have tried:

I want to show a tooltip that has HTML content, however data-tip accepts only "string" and not html. Hence now im using react component  to show the tooltip content.

Now I want to pass the tooltip content to my react component that I'll use to show the tooltip, but for that I need to find a way to pass the content defined:

```
let element = (
    <div>
       <div> test</div>
        <div> <span> test333</span></div>
    </div>
    )
    <div data-react = {element}></div>
```

hence I used: `<div data-tip = {ReactDOMServer.renderToString(elements)}></div>`

with this in my tooltip component
 `<Tooltip>
     const tipvalue = e.target.getAttribute("data-tip")` ;

I get `data-tip` value as a string, now I want to pass this to my react component to render the html.

```
<Tooltip>
<ReactTooltip content = {tipvalue}/>
</Tooltip>


export default class ReactToolTip extends PureComponent {

  render() {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.props.content, "application/xml");
    const htmlSections = doc;
      return (
        {htmlSections}
      );
  }
}
```

however this gives me:
[image]

not sure how to render it in the component after this? 
any ideass???

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is no code like console.log or anything which would print `"object Object"`. Also, what are you trying to do with `data-react`?

Comment: @palaѕн: this is just an attribute I'm trying to use to get the dom element inside my toltip, so that I can use this content to render using a React component. I'll update my question

Comment: Ok, maybe you can try to look into [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) - Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.

Comment: The question is why do you need to do this? What are you trying to do? We could try to help you if you could provide some context.

Comment: @jperl: updated my question, thanks

Comment: Why not simply do `<ReactTooltip content = {element}/>` with element being `let element = ( <div> <div> test</div> <div> <span> test333</span></div> </div> )` ? What is `<div data-react = {element}></div>` for?

Comment: @jperl: this is accept dynamic content, the above will defeats the purpose of accpeting dynamic content... there would ideally be no point if we define the html content in the component, because then we are restricitng the compoent to certain HTML structure

Comment: Yes, I get it. But why do you need to store it in an attribute? As palaѕн suggested, when you want to access DOM elements, you usually use refs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this example will be helpful. Probably if you are getting `example` variable from other context, it is better to use `var` or `const` variable declaration

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

var element = (
<div>
   <div> test</div>
    <div> <span> test333</span></div>
</div>
);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {element}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[this code on repl.it playground](https://repl.it/@EugeneShashkov/CompetentRemoteDatamart)

Answer (score 1):

If that didn't work, you should try making a component out of it and then you can pass the props of the father component to it.

```
function Element() {
   return (
      <div>
          <div>test</div>
          <div><span>test333</span></div>
      </div>
   )
}
<Element />
```

Comment: it still comes out as ```object Object```

Comment: what do you want the output to be ? the markup inside ?

Comment: @JoãoMarcello: updated my question with the screenshot of the o/p.thanks

Comment: so you want to serialize the component into a string ? (keep in mind you can only render a string here). I guess JSON.stringify(component) would work in some way but... It's a very strange behiavor and your probably not using the right strategy here.

Comment: I think you should be making a component, like I showed you, and if you want to make something dynamic inside it, you pass as a prop to the <Element />. Passing this element as a variable won't make sense...

Comment: I think that makes more sense now, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @KevinGilbert: updated my question with clarification, hope that helps, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately can't do this. Even if React look like HTML, they're not working the same. Your data-react attribute can only contains string.

Answer (score 0):

Since react only keep `string` or `number` attributes in the DOM, you can only convert them to string to keep it there:

```
<div data-react={String(element)}>
```

I don't know how are you going to use that elsewhere, but honestly why you would ever need that ? :) I suggest think about [Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)s